# Did anyone try to use the react-facebook npm to insert FB component on your react app?

Tags: reactjs

I have tried hard to follow the codes on https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook

Although i am a React.js beginner , i am sure that the component was rendered in the page. But the page is still a blank page.

Did anyone encounter the same problem and solved it?